# Haskell <<loop>>

Tags: list, sorting, loops, haskell, indexing

With `getIndex xs y` I want the index of the first sublist in `xs` whose length is greater than `y`.

The output is:

```
[[],[4],[4,3],[3,5,3],[3,5,5,6,1]]
aufgabe6: <<loop>>
```

why `getIndex` does not work?

```
import Data.List

-- Die Sortierfunktion --
myCompare a b
    | length a < length b = LT
    | otherwise = GT

sortList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortList x = sortBy myCompare x

-- Die Indexfunktion --
getIndex :: [[a]] -> Int -> Int
getIndex [] y = 0
getIndex (x:xs) y
    | length x <= y = 1 + getIndex xs y
    | otherwise = 0
    where (x:xs) = sortList (x:xs)

main = do
    print (sortList [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]])
    print (getIndex [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 2)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Getting it to terminate

The problem is in this case

```
getIndex (x:xs) y
    | length x <= y = 1 + getIndex xs y
    | otherwise = 0
    where (x:xs) = sortList (x:xs)
```

You're confusing which `(x:xs)` is which. You should instead do

```
getIndex zs y
    | length x <= y = 1 + getIndex xs y
    | otherwise = 0
    where (x:xs) = sortList zs
```

giving

```
Main> main
[[],[4],[4,3],[3,5,3],[3,5,5,6,1]]
3
*Main> getIndex [[],[2],[4,5]] 1
2
*Main> getIndex [[],[2],[4,5]] 5
3
```

This gives you the number of the first list of length at least `y` in the sorted list, which actually answers the question "How many lists are of length at most `y` in the original?"

## How can we find out other facts?

If you want position from the original list, you can tag the entries with their position, using `zip`:

```
*Main> zip [1..] [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]]
[(1,[4]),(2,[3,5,3]),(3,[4,3]),(4,[3,5,5,6,1]),(5,[])]
```

Let's make a utility function for working with those:

```
hasLength likeThis (_,xs) = likeThis (length xs)
```

We can use it like this:

```
*Main> hasLength (==4) (1,[1,2,3,4])
True
*Main> filter (hasLength (>=2)) (zip [1..] ["","yo","hi there","?"])
[(2,"yo"),(3,"hi there")]
```

Which means it's now easy to write a function that gives you the index of the first list of length longer than `y`:

```
whichIsLongerThan xss y = 
    case filter (hasLength (>y)) (zip [1..] xss) of
         [] -> error "nothing long enough" -- change this to 0 or (length xss + 1) if you prefer
         (x:xs) -> fst x
```

This gives us

```
*Main> whichIsLongerThan [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 2
2
*Main> whichIsLongerThan [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 3
4
*Main> whichIsLongerThan [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 0
1
```

### Shorter?

but we can do similar tricks:

```
whichIsShorterThan xss y = 
    case filter (hasLength (<y)) (zip [1..] xss) of
         [] -> error "nothing short enough" -- change this to 0 or (length xss + 1) if you prefer
         (x:xs) -> fst x
```

so you get

```
*Main> whichIsShorterThan [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 2
1
*Main> whichIsShorterThan [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 1
5
*Main> whichIsShorterThan [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 0
*** Exception: nothing short enough
```

## Generalised

Let's pull out the common theme there:

```
whichLength :: (Int -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> Int
whichLength likeThis xss = 
    case filter (hasLength likeThis) (zip [1..] xss) of
         [] -> error "nothing found" -- change this to 0 or (length xss + 1) if you prefer
         (x:xs) -> fst x
```

so we can do

```
*Main> whichLength (==5) [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 
4
*Main> whichLength (>2) [[4],[3,5,3],[4,3],[3,5,5,6,1],[]] 
2
```

Comment: Very nice and thorough answer. I appreciate knowing the thought process not just the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `index of the firs sublist with length > y`? If that's not the goal (and `< y` is), then

```
length x <= y = 1 + getIndex xs y
```

should be

```
length x >= y = 1 + getIndex xs y
```

Also, `(x:xs) = sortList (x:xs)` is [bottom](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom), since it will never end. If you want to sort it somehow, you might follow AndrewC's solution.

Answer (score 0):

`let` (and `where`) bindings in Haskell are *recursive*: LHS and RHS both belong (and thus refer to) to the same new scope. Your code is equivalent to

```
........
getIndex (x:xs) y = 
  let                  -- new, extended scope, containing definitions for 
      (x:xs) = a       --   new variables x, xs, a ... the original vars x, xs
      a = sortList a   --   are inaccessible, __shadowed__ by new definitions
  in                   -- evaluated inside the new, extended scope
    if length x <= y         -- x refers to the new definition
      then 1 + getIndex xs y
      else 0
```

When the value of `x` is demanded by `length`, its new definition `(x:xs) = a` demands the value of `a`, which is directly defined in terms of itself, `a = sortList a`:

```
a = sortList a
  = sortList (sortList a)
  = sortList (sortList (sortList a))
  = sortList (sortList (sortList (sortList a)))
  = ....
```

A *black hole*.